# FCM notification received twice when in the background (service worker)

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

When im triggering a notification with my website in the background or close, i get two notifications.  The first one has missing elements in the payload (icon for example) while the 2nd one has all the info.

The code is running on this site: https://www.maltachamber.org.mt

https://www.maltachamber.org.mt/firebase-messaging-sw.js

The foreground notification also works as intended, the code is at line 2782 for the homepage.

Comment: Maybe because you are registering the sw mannually? firebase load the sw by default, you just have to put the static file in the root (which in your case it's already done)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with a workaround.
Override the push Event with a custom Event class then use the listnerto intercept the incoming messages and use the custom class to re-push the events but without the 'notification' key exposed so firebase won't consider it.
In this way they won't be showed twice.

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
    notificationOptions = { /*...*/ };
    self.registration.showNotification("Title",notificationOptions);
});


class CustomPushEvent extends Event {
    constructor(data) {
        super('push')

        Object.assign(this, data)
        this.custom = true
    }
}

self.addEventListener('push', (e) => {
    console.log("PUSH");
    // Skip if event is our own custom event
    if (e.custom) return;

    // Keep old event data to override
    let oldNotificationWrapper = e.data

    // Create a new event to dispatch, pull values from notification key and put it in data key,
    // and then remove notification key
    let newEvent = new CustomPushEvent({
        data: {
            json() {
                let newNotificationWrapper= oldNotificationWrapper.json()
                newNotificationWrapper.data = {
                    ...newNotificationWrapper.data,
                    ...newNotificationWrapper.notification
                }
                delete newNotificationWrapper.notification
                return newNotificationWrapper
            },
        },
        waitUntil: e.waitUntil.bind(e),
    })

    // Stop event propagation
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()

    // Dispatch the new wrapped event
    dispatchEvent(newEvent)
});
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers already provided.

Comment: @DaveL17 Can you just show us where is the `other answers already provided`?

Comment: @AjayMakwana If yours is the only answer when I reviewed it, I should've deleted that last clause from my comment. It is also possible that there was another answer that has since been deleted. Feel free to ignore that bit.  Cheers.

Comment: @DaveL17 
Okay, thanks. FYI: I didn't answer here, I'm looking for the same solution.

Comment: @DaveL17 Also, I didn't answer this as I'm looking for the same solution, so it is unlikely that you reviewed my answer. BTW You are doing good job. Cheers!